# Can Oracle 11g Express Edition Work on Parallels

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I am using a Mac and need to use Oracle 11g. I have Parallels installed with Windows 8.1 on it. Do I need to download anything else or just download Oracle 11g Express Edition and run it?

Comment: You can also just download a pre-configure VirtualBox image: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html

Answer (score 1):

Better solution would be to install docker or virtualbox and run the OracleXe image within one of those containers. Once docker is running you can easily launch a new OracleXe container with two commands. Already configured to allow easy access via SQLDeveloper. I tested my own steps by downloading the docker toolbox, installing and running the OracleXe image. Everything started up without an issue on my desktop. If all possible I would run this on a droplet at DigitalOcean since Oracle is a hog on space 2.3G!

OracleXe container can be found here: [OracleXe Docker Container](https://hub.docker.com/r/alexeiled/docker-oracle-xe-11g/)
Docker Install on Mac: [Docker Install](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_one/)